# How to send keyboard signals to two separate computers (arduino due)

Tags: arduino-due, keyboard

The arduino due has 2 micro-usb ports that you can connect to two separate computers. I need to send different keyboard signals to each computer. How would I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can the 2nd MCU on the UNO R3 be used for keyboard emulation?](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/991/can-the-2nd-mcu-on-the-uno-r3-be-used-for-keyboard-emulation)

Comment: Guess what the other USB connector on the Due is connected to. That's right, a ATmega16U2.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams except that is not what he is asking. He's asking "How to send keyboard signals to two separate computers" of which he has a theory that because it has two USB ports, this should be possible. Even if this isn't the case, the other answer doesn't answer his question.

Comment: @JakeC: It actually does. The answer is "reprogram the '16U2 to act as a keyboard". Communication between the SAM3X and the '16U2 is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams But because it doesn't specifically address multiple computers, it doesn't fulfill the criteria of a duplicate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the Arduino Due has two separate USB ports, only one of them is a native port accessible to the processor. The second port is only usable for programming, and is connected to a different and much smaller chip that handles the programming task.

To connect to multiple computers from an Arduino Due, you have two options:

- You can [reprogram the second MCU](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/991/can-the-2nd-mcu-on-the-uno-r3-be-used-for-keyboard-emulation) to allow it to connect to the computer as a keyboard. This method is tricky because it requires an external programmer for it to work.
- You can use a software USB implementation such as [V-USB](https://www.obdev.at/products/vusb/index.html) to use regular digital pins to connect to the computer. This is also tricky because it requires a little electronic know how a few extra components to make this work.

Both options require a little something else to make it work, so you will have to pick based on what you feel more comfortable doing.

Answer (score 1):

For one of them, use [`Keyboard`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/MouseKeyboard) as you normally would.

For the other, do whatever [Can the 2nd MCU on the UNO R3 be used for keyboard emulation?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/991/can-the-2nd-mcu-on-the-uno-r3-be-used-for-keyboard-emulation) tells you to do to reprogram the ATmega16U2 connected to the other USB connector.